# DynamicReport title band

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

i need to adjust the title band width to table width. Anyone knows how to do that?

Im using this code

```
private FastReportBuilder modrb;

            modrb.setTitle(getTitulo());
            modrb.setSubtitle(getSubTitulo());
```

And...

```
    DynamicReport dr = modrb.build();
    dr.setAllowDetailSplit(false);
    dr.getOptions().setUseFullPageWidth(true);
    dr.getOptions().setRightMargin(0);
```

Comment: @AlexK I have found that my problem was the title band, if i remove it my table works perfect but i need to adjust it to the size of the table

Comment: I fixed it setting the width of Page item

Comment: If your issue is solved you can post solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it setting the width of Page item, i took all columns width and then set the page size to all columns+100 px , it works fine now

Comment: Having actual code would make this answer better. Please also be sure to have enough code in your question so that people can see that this is actually the answer to the problem.